# Analytical solution to short-sale constrained portfolio

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, optimization, mean-variance

Say that we want to find the efficient mean-variance portfolio (i.e. minimize variance given that weights sum to 1 and given a set target return) and impose a short sale constraint such that $w_i \geq 0$ for each $i$.

My textbook states that Lagrange multipliers cannot be used to analytically solve this problem (which I understand), so my question is if there exists an analytical solution? (Perhaps using KKT-conditions?)

Comment: Unfortunately not, an iterative procedure must be applied until the KKT conditions are satisfied (roughly speaking trial and error must be used to cycle through various candidate solutions until the Complementary Slackness part of KKT is satisfied), so a closed form solution does not exist.

Comment: @nbbo2 Okay, thank you. Do you know if the same applies to mean-variance portfolio where we switch the return constraint to an inequality (i.e. min var given weight sum 1 and given portfolio return *equal or greater than* target return)?

Comment: In THAT case the problem Min Variance with return *greater than or equal* gives the same solution as *equal* (because of the geometry of the efficient frontier), so people use *equal* without loss of generality to simplify the math.

Comment: The solution will only be the same for the efficient part of the minimum variance frontier. The calculation will result in all portfolios on the minimum variance frontier, which includes inefficient portfolios. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: That's correct, so knowing where the Global Minimum Variance Portfolio is, is important; that's the boundary between the lower (inefficient part) of the curve and the efficient part .